# Make a flash effect

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Can we make something like flash effect in cocos2d?
I mean increase color to some value in N seconds and then decrease it to alpha. 
Any ideas?

Comment: To what do you want to apply the flash effect? An element in a view? The whole view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use : [Particle Designer](http://particledesigner.71squared.com)